# iframe doesn't embed, just pops up with open with/save as box. Tried everything

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe

All I want to do is embed this banner, I have tried every possible combination and googled as much as I can.  Here are my current live attempts.

Non wordpress - http://mch.co.uk/centrallondon/iframetest.shtml

With this code:

```
<iframe 
    src="http://www.mch.co.uk/centrallondon/immac.html" 
    width="445"
    height="85" 
    scrolling="no"
    frameborder="0"  ></iframe>
```

Wordpress - http://mch.co.uk/centrallondon/iframe-test.shtml

With this code:

```
[iframe 
    width="640"
    height="480"
    src="http://www.mch.co.uk/centrallondon/immac.html"]
<iframe 
    src="http://www.mch.co.uk/centrallondon/immac.html"
    width="445"
    height="85" 
    frameborder="0"
    scrolling="no">
 </iframe>
```

The wordpress one includes a shortcode from an iframe embedding plugin.

Comment: Your problem is not with the iframe itself. Turns out that http://www.mch.co.uk/centrallondon/immac.html is actually popping up a save dialog. There must be a javascript file triggering this dialog.

Comment: ok, the file was made using Google Swiffy.

I've just made another one, it works fine offline but when I upload it it's just blank - http://www.mch.co.uk/centrallondon/sjp.htm

At least it's not popping up with a save dialog...I'm so lost though.